# Angular.JS Fails to show right "time" from time mongo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I know android code but outsourced the website to external party.
The vendor uses "Angular.js" to build the website.

From server, the time is "**November 28, 2016 on 16:42**" UTC.
However, the result from my vendor is "**2016/29/42 12:42**".

P.S.
I don't know about angular.js but want to know how to display the time probably there. If there are any mistakes, please feel free to point out.

[image]

Comment: well we need some piece of code how your trying to display and probably a plunker with your problem will be much helpful to us.... to find the correct solution for you

Comment: The keyword is "UTC". The computer is in UTC+8 - which happens to be [the current offset of HK](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=HK+timezone) so: JAN29 12:42am (HK) - 8 = JAN28 16:42pm (UTC). Thus, it's the correct "actual" time, just converted/displayed in a non-local timezone.

Comment: Thanks the advice, i got more color.
I basically think the vendor get the "monthday" with minute, and the month with "monthday", which leads to very strange date format